# How to get inserted row IDs for bulk/batch insert with wpdb query?

Tags: plugin-development, database, query, wpdb, bulk

I'm writing a plugin where I need to save data in custom tables, `function` hits an API and then saves data for which I need bulk `insert`, but as `wpdb` doesn't support it out of the box I made a `function` for it using `prepare` and `query`.

But `query` doesn't return inserted row IDs. How can I get them? Any other way or anything besides using `wpdb`?

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637367/mysql-last-insert-id-used-with-multiple-records-insert-statement):

> If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement,
> LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted
> row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce
> easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.

So if you need every inserted ID you should use single `$wpdb->insert` commands, then you have the ID available for each with `$wpdb->insert_id`. Docs here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_row

If you insert many rows with a single query you can't get all the inserted ID's, unless you e.g. wanted to re-query for them if you are sure you can identify those rows uniquely.

Comment: yes, I know that already, thing is single inserts impact database more as opposed to bulk inserts, and I will have multiple tables with datasets to insert so I can't rely on that, as it might break.

Comment: @ateebahmed you can't have it both ways ;-) so if you want to do a bulk insert then you need to SELECT again to find the ID's

Comment: yeah thanks, I'm doing it already, wanted to know if I can somehow bypass wpdb itself and call the underlying db class or if php provide any way to get all ids in an array